# Create Google Calendar entry from Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I'm completely new to Google Apps Script, but I think this is a pretty basic application that I'm hoping someone can help me with.

Basically, I'd like to create a basic Google Calendar entry from Google Sheets data.

Here is the spreadsheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Av2PWLzDKHzz8kVuJF3Ykbn_G_0D3doXy3YaPjapB2Q/edit?usp=sharing

The event date would be Column A.  Start time Column B.  End time Column C.  Event description Column D.

I'd like to share or send the calendar entry to other people so they can add it to the calendar.

Any help on getting started is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to write a preliminary script. Start simple - read a ranges' values, create an event, send an email - and then increase complexity by linking these scripts to exchange data. One way to keep things easy is to write functions that only achieve one purpose - "this function gets data from a sheet", "that function makes HTML from its inputs", etc. Your starting point is the Google Apps Script documentation, and your preferred JavaScript textbook / tutorials / developer reference.

Comment: cool, thanks for the guidance on getting started